# Scrapy is not Crawling the next page url

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

My spider is not crawling the page 2 but the XPath is returning the correct next page link which is an absolute link to next page.

Here is my code

```
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.http import Request, FormRequest



class MintSpiderSpider(Spider):

    name = 'Mint_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
        urls =  response.xpath('//div[@class = "post-inner post-hover"]/h2/a/@href').extract()

        for url in urls:
            yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_lyrics)

        next_page_url = response.xpath('//li[@class="next right"]/a/@href').extract_first()
        if next_page_url:
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page_url, callback=self.parse)


    def parse_foo(self, response):
        info = response.xpath('//*[@class="songinfo"]/p/text()').extract()
        name =  response.xpath('//*[@id="lyric"]/h2/text()').extract()

        yield{
            'name' : name,
            'info': info
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scrapy: Following pagination link to scrape data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52246009/scrapy-following-pagination-link-to-scrape-data)

Comment: Please correct the indentation.

Comment: Actually, the indentation was right I accidentally posted it in two parts now it's fine you can check sir.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `next_page_url` is a list, and it needs to be an url as a string. You need to use the `extract_first()` function instead of `extract()` in `next_page_url = response.xpath('//li[@class="next right"]/a/@href').extract()`.

**UPDATE**

You have to `import scrapy` since you are using `yield scrapy.Request(next_page_url, callback=self.parse)`

Comment: Thanks sir and this ` next_page_url = response.xpath('//li[@class="next right"]/a/@href').extract()
            if next_page_url:
                yield scrapy.Request(next_page_url, callback=self.parse)` should be out of the for loop right?

Comment: Yes, if not, you will request the `next_page_url` every time you request one of page's url.

Comment: Sir, I Indedntend the code the way you told but in the Next_page_url line it is showing indentation error but everything looks perfect here it's out of the loop too.

Comment: I edited your post with correct indent, copy paste it, and double check the indent

Comment: Dear sir, I did exactly what you said but scrappy only crawled the first page and then stopped

Comment: Have you checked that the xpath is correct ? That you correctly get an url ? What is the website you are scraping ?

Comment: Thanks a ton sir you are a true legend