# How to stop scrapy from crawling when it reaches the starting point of previous run

Tags: python, scrapy

I am making a spider which will crawl the entire site on the first run and store the data in my database.

But I will keep running this spider on weekly basis to get the updates of the crawled site in my database and I don't want scrapy to crawl the pages which are already present in my database how to achieve this I have made two plans -

1] Make a crawler to fetch the entire site and somehow store the first fetched URL in a csv file then keep following the next pages. Then make another crawler which will start fetching backwards that means it will take the input from the URL in csv and keep running till prev_page exits this way I will get the data, but the url in csv will be crawled twice.

2] Make a crawler which will check condition if the data is in the database then stop, is it possible? This will be the most productive way but I can't find the way out. Maybe making logs files might help in some way?

**Update** 
The site is a blog which updates frequently and sorted as latest post on the top manner

Comment: It's hard to tell which solution suits best if you do not provide more infos on the website. Could you tell us which one is scraped and how it's getting updated ? For example, is there a page where new articles are shown in first positions (like a blog ?)

Comment: Yes you got it right its just like a blog

Comment: Again, it depends on lot of things. Do you scrap the main page, yield url of articles, then scrap content of each article ? In this case, does an article keep the same url over time ? Or do you scrap content from the main page directly ?

Comment: Yes it takes the same URL forever and I fetch some part of the content on every url/blog post of the site and keep doing it on every page

Comment: So every time you scrap an article you can add the url to the database, and check if you have already scraped the url before yielding it again ?

Comment: I don't save the URL actually I scrape the title which is unique for every post it would be better if I check for Title, But I can still save the URL in the database don't show it in the front end

Comment: Sir I have updated the question can you show me how to achieve this?

Comment: I would need to see the Spider class to help you more

Comment: Hello sir here is the spider https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52501149/scrapy-is-not-crawling-the-next-page-url/52501701#52501701

Answer (score 1):

Something like this :

```
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.http import Request, FormRequest



class MintSpiderSpider(Spider):

    name = 'Mint_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
        urls =  response.xpath('//div[@class = "post-inner post-hover"]/h2/a/@href').extract()

        for url in urls:
            if never_visited(url, database):
                yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_lyrics) #do you mean parse_foo ?

        next_page_url = response.xpath('//li[@class="next right"]/a/@href').extract_first()
        if next_page_url:
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page_url, callback=self.parse)


    def parse_foo(self, response):
        save_url(response.request.url, database)
        info = response.xpath('//*[@class="songinfo"]/p/text()').extract()
        name =  response.xpath('//*[@id="lyric"]/h2/text()').extract()

        yield{
            'name' : name,
            'info': info
        }
```

You just need to implement never_visited and save_url functions.
never_visited will check in your database if url is already there. save_url will add the url into your database.